# Generic NSMapTable replacement written in Swift

Tags: generics, hash-map, swift

This is my attempt at writing a generic `NSMapTable` with weak keys and strong values (after your feedback I'll be trying to write Strong-Key/Weak-Value and Weak-Key/Weak-Value variants to have the complete functionality of `NSMapTable` with generics). To my knowledge it works correctly.

```
public class WeakKeyDictionary<K: AnyObject, V where K: Hashable> {

    private var dict = Dictionary<HashableWeakBox<K>, V>()
    public var block: (V)->() = { _ in }

    public init() {}
    public init(dictionary: Dictionary<K, V>) {
        for (k, v) in dictionary {
            setValue(v, forKey: k)
        }
    }

    public subscript(key: K) -> V? {
        get { return valueForKey(key) }
        set { setValue(newValue, forKey: key) }
    }

    public func valueForKey(key: K) -> V? {
        return dict[HashableWeakBox(key)]
    }
    public func setValue(newValue: V?, forKey key: K) {
        let hashableBox = HashableWeakBox(key)

        if let value = newValue {
            let watcher = DeallocWatcher { [weak self] in
                if let v = self?.dict[hashableBox] { self?.block(v) }
                self?.dict[hashableBox] = nil
            }

            objc_setAssociatedObject(key, unsafeAddressOf(self), watcher, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
            dict[hashableBox] = value
        }
        else {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(key, unsafeAddressOf(self), nil, 0)
            dict[hashableBox] = nil
        }
    }
    public func removeValueForKey(key: K) -> V? {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(key, unsafeAddressOf(self), nil, 0)
        return dict.removeValueForKey(HashableWeakBox(key))
    }

    public var count: Int { return dict.count }
    public var isEmpty: Bool { return dict.isEmpty }
    public var keyValues: [(K, V)] {
        var list = [(K, V)]()
        for (k, v) in dict { list.append((k.value!, v)) }
        return list
    }
    public var keys: [K] {
        var list = [K]()
        for k in dict.keys { list.append(k.value!) }
        return list
    }
    public var values: [V] {
        return Array(dict.values)
    }

    deinit {
        for box in dict.keys {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(box.value, unsafeAddressOf(self), nil, 0)
        }
    }
}

private func == <T: Hashable>(l: T, r: T) -> Bool { return l.hashValue == r.hashValue }

private class HashableWeakBox<T: AnyObject where T: Hashable>: Hashable {
    weak var value: T?
    let hashValueWhenNil: Int

    init(_ v: T) {
        value = v
        hashValueWhenNil = v.hashValue
    }

    var hashValue: Int { return value?.hashValue ?? hashValueWhenNil }
}

private class DeallocWatcher {
    let callback: ()->()
    init(_ c: ()->()) { callback = c }
    deinit { callback() }
}
```

The trick needed in order to be notified when one of the keys disappears is to add a watcher object (`DeallocWatcher`) as an associated object of the key (this only works on Swift 1.2, if I'm not mistaken). That way, whenever the key disappears, so does the watcher object, which in turn warns the dictionary class when `deinit`ing.

The `block` property should, if needed, be set by the code using the class, and provides a way to be notified whenever a key is removed from the dictionary.

I'd like to know if this is reliable and works correctly in all cases. I'd also like to have a better idea of under which conditions can this be used across multiple threads. Finally, I'd like feedback on how I can better follow Swift guidelines and implement common "Swift-isms".

Answer (score 5):

(Not a full review, but some remarks and suggestions.)

Generally, your code looks correct to me, I could not see obvious
errors or problems – for the *single-threaded* usage.

You cannot
assume that it will work correctly when used from *multiple threads*
simultaneously. 
Cocoa mutable collection types are not thread-safe (see [Thread Safety Summary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html)),
and – as far as I know – the same applies to Swift collections
(references: [Swift: process Array in parallel using GCD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693838/swift-process-array-in-parallel-using-gcd/26790019#26790019), [Swift mutable array thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340527/swift-mutable-array-thread-safety), [Swift Arrays are not Threadsafe](http://blog.human-friendly.com/swift-arrays-are-not-threadsafe)).

---

In

```
let watcher = DeallocWatcher { [weak self] in
    if let v = self?.dict[hashableBox] { self?.block(v) }
    self?.dict[hashableBox] = nil
}
```

`self` is (conditionally) unwrapped three times. I would use 
optional binding instead so that it is unwrapped only once.
You could also take advantage of the fact that `removeValueForKey()`
returns the old value (or `nil`):

```
let watcher = DeallocWatcher { [weak self] in
    if let s = self {
        if let v = s.dict.removeValueForKey(hashableBox) {
            s.block(v)
        }
    }
}
```

---

When a value for key is removed in

```
    else {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(key, unsafeAddressOf(self), nil, 0)
        dict[hashableBox] = nil // <-- not needed!
    }
```

then the first line already causes the value to be removed from `dict`,
because disassociating the associated object fires the `DeallocWatcher`
callback. So the second line is not needed.

---

The `keys` and `keyValues` properties can be simplified using `map()`:

```
public var keyValues: [(K, V)] {
    return map(dict) { (k, v) -> (K, V) in (k.value!, v) }
}

public var keys: [K] {
    return Array(dict.keys.map { $0.value! })
}
```

---

You can also easily add conformance to additional protocols to make
your `WeakKeyDictionary` more look and feel like a real dictionary.

If you add the `Printable` protocol

```
public class WeakKeyDictionary<K: AnyObject, V where K: Hashable> : Printable {

    // ...
    public var description: String  {
        return "[ " + ", ".join(map(dict) { (k, v) in "\(k.value!) : \(v) " }) + "]"
    }
}
```

then `println(wkdict)` produces an output similar to a dictionary.

And with `SequenceType`

```
public class WeakKeyDictionary<K: AnyObject, V where K: Hashable> : Printable, SequenceType {

    // ...
    public func generate() -> GeneratorOf<(K, V)> {
        var gen = dict.generate()
        return GeneratorOf {
            if let (k, v) = gen.next() {
                return (k.value!, v)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

you can enumerate keys and values like

```
for (k, v) in wkdict {
    println((k, v))
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first section (up until the first horizontal line): It seems I forgot to mention an important detail (my bad). The `block` property should be set by the code using the class, so that it can react to whenever a key is removed from the dictionary. The value you see (`{ v in }`) is just a placeholder. Also, I'm not sure `self` is guaranteed to be non-nil when the callback is called...

Comment: Regarding the other sections: thanks! Those are some good comments!

Comment: @Alex: I see (I could have guessed that because it is a *public* property). – You are right that `self` actually *can* be nil, I will remove that part. (My argumentation was that `deinit` removes all associations, so that no watchers exist anymore. But that's wrong, the keys can live longer than the map table.)

Comment: @Alex: I have updated the first section, taking the block property into account.

Comment: About thread-safety: I think you're right, this class is not thread-safe. However (I just thought about this now), the deallocations of the keys *can* happen on any thread, and thus it is possible for the underlying dictionary to be changed on any thread... \*ponders\*

Comment: @Alex: We can continue the discussion tomorrow, it is too late for me now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22546/discussion-between-alex-and-martin-r).

Answer (score 1):

There's one thing I missed that would make this class more "Swift-like": implementing `DictionaryLiteralConvertible`. If `WeakKeyDictionary` conforms to that protocol, this line:

```
let weakDict = WeakKeyDictionary(dictionary: [key1: v1, key2: v2, key3: v3])
```

can be written like this:

```
let weakDict: WeakKeyDictionary = [key1: v1, key2: v2, key3: v3]
```

which is much cleaner and more in line with the other Swift types.

That protocol is very easy to implement:

```
public convenience required init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (K, V)...) {
    var dict = [K:V]()
    for (k, v) in elements { dict[k] = v }
    self.init(dictionary: dict)
}
```